# voice activity detection within the browser

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

So this is a tricky one.

I wish to write a web application which records a word said by the user, and then sends the samples to the server side for processing.

The algorithm I have in mind is as follows:

1. start a recording session once the user has clicked on a button
2. wait for the user to have said a single word (assuming he know he's supposed to say a single word)
3. stop the recording once he said it
4. send the samples to the server, say using HTTP
5. process the signal on the server side
6. send some response back to the user.

There are several solution for Voice Activity Detection in Java,C#, and other high level languages I presume. 
However, I wish this part would to be done on the Client side (otherwise, I'll have to send too much data from the client to the server which is highly inefficient) I.E in javascript and HTML5.

I'm not an experienced web developer, so my questions are:
Is this feasible? Is there a library for that (I haven't found any)? 
What would be the best approach in approaching the problem?

Comment: You can process audio on client side. Look into [Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) combined with [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia). Just note that the API is currently in draft mode. Best implementation so far seem to be with Chrome (FF had a proprietary implementation but is working on shifting implementation towards the drafted standard).

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice vad npm with browser support here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ricky0123/vad

You will need to add the CDNs:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ricky0123/vad/dist/index.browser.js"></script>
<script>
async function startVad(){
      const myvad = await vad.MicVAD.new({
        onFrameProcessed: (probabilities) => {

        },
        onSpeechStart: () => {},
        onVADMisfire: () => {},
        onSpeechEnd: (audio) => {console.log("spoke");},
      })
      myvad.start()

}
startVad();
</script>
```